# Get (sub) directories matching a pattern

Tags: gradle

I have a directory structure that contains directories namend "plugin" on multiple levels amongst other dirs and files. I need to get the collection of  all "plugin" directories since I want to use them as workingDirectory later.

Is there a smarter way than recursively interate over all files and check if they are directories and if they have the name "relDir"?

I looked at FileTree and tried to use filter() or matching(), but whatever I do, I get an empty result.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Finally,

```
def pluginDirs = []
        file('src/main/js/myPlugins').eachDirRecurse {
            dir ->
                if (dir.name == "plugin") {
                    pluginDirs << dir
                }
        }
        pluginDirs.each {
            println it.path
        }
```

did it.